# TypeScript: Generic extends object with only optional keys

Tags: typescript

I have a function with overload

```
export function someFunc<P extends undefined>(): () => string

export function someFunc<P extends object>(): (params: P) => string

export function someFunc<P extends object | undefined>() {
    // ...implementation
}
```

The thing I'd like to achieve is to be able to add one more overload for the case where `P` doesn't have any required keys, eg

```
const obj: P = { foo?: string, bar?: string } // matches
const obj2: P = { foo: string, bar?: string } // doesn't match
```

the overload would look something like this:

```
export function someFunc<P extends NoOptionalKeys>(): (params?: P) => string
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't know if I've ever seen overloads used in this way; I suppose you expect the caller to manually specify the `P` generic, and then have the compiler pick the call signature from that, since the call signatures are all zero-argument and there's nothing from which to infer `P` automatically.  So I'm assuming you're looking for something like this:

```
const fUndef = someFunc<undefined>();
// () => string
const fSomeReq = someFunc<{ a: string, b?: string }>();
// (params: {a: string, b?: string}) => string;
const fNoReq = someFunc<{ a?: string, b?: string }>();
// (params?: {a?: string, b?: string}) => string;
```

Doing this with overloads is a bit strange because [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) are upper bounds.  `P extends XXX` means that `P` must be some *subtype* of `XXX` (so it should be `XXX`, or something narrower than `XXX`).

But in TypeScript, an object with all optional properties is a *supertype* of the same object with any required properties, not a *subtype*. So the thing you're looking for is essentially a *lower bound* generic constraint, but TypeScript doesn't directly support that.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) for more information.)  You'd want to say something like `P super Partial<P>` instead of `P extends Partial<P>`.  Or, equivalently, `Partial<P> extends P`, but generic constraints don't work that way.

You can simulate lower bound constraints using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types), so instead of `P extends UpperBound super LowerBound`, you can write `P extends (LowerBound extends P ? UpperBound : never)` and it has a chance of working.   For you, that means this:

```
function someFunc<P extends undefined>(): () => string;
function someFunc<P extends (Partial<P> extends P ? object : never)>(): (params?: P) => string
function someFunc<P extends object>(): (params: P) => string;
function someFunc() {
    return null!
}
```

I put this as the second overload; it needs to come before the regular `object` overload so that it has higher priority.  If you check this code, the above `fUndef`, `fSomeReq`, and `fNoReq` are typed the way you expect.

---

Another possible way to proceed is to give only a single call signature and use conditional types to calculate the function output type.  Something like this:

```
function someFunc<P extends object | undefined>(): (...params:
    P extends undefined ? [] :
    Partial<P> extends P ? [P?] :
    [P]
) => string;
function someFunc() {
    return null!
}
```

This should behave very similarly (and you'll see that `fUndef`, `fSomeReq`, and `fNoReq` are the right types), but allows us to write our logic a little more straightforwardly: `Partial<P> extends P` instead of the reverse, because `P` is already determined by the caller and instead of verifying a constraint, we're testing it with conditional types.

Notice that the return type above is a single callable with a [tuple-typed rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) that's conditionally determined.  I did that because all three output types are callables returning a `string`.  You could write it out like this instead:

```
function someFunc<P extends object | undefined>():
    P extends undefined ? () => string :
    Partial<P> extends P ? (params?: P) => string :
    (params: P) => string
function someFunc() {
    return null!
}
```

which might be more obviously related to your overloads.  Either way should work.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbhATgGwPYgBMkBvAWACgKlqkAzAV2HgBcBLXYJKXSAMUfgAeAApIIAD2YRgBKEkYEItVsAgEAfAAoAlAC4kOpAF51XZphUBzANxUaDJmw5ceEfkxFjJ02QeEhMNhBsEVMJKRk5UQB+JFwAIwArCBYkfVUMTG0tPQM4THAoaP1hbWNTKHMrO2oHFnZObj4BT3CfOQTklhz9TXzCkrKTMwtgGxq6ASdG13d4QzJyGmWkTAhmekxOYHpsbABCCYBfCgn4Dkq6AFUZJWMXZo8FJRU1HNslmgB6L4MhiqqYzOF2YdAAyq4AEoQACO9yabhaxCQIH0lVGlgANEh4sURlYkEd3hMfnkAgMSKj8WNsbi0YDLEd-tTxp9qOdgJdaAA5XDQuFGB6IjzIkB49FWWnihmE4lspCkvrksBFfTEMX0jFSzVWJnlFkfE6UcigSCwBDIADCHAIrGmwRIEzq0yFc1a3kicSSKVBAB95LdlKoNDpegA6CP9FW6CbLURtT3PINqJCxADaAF00rGaP5AqxgqEvBFfDEkGnhNEszH5csKxmJsyJWMPstnQ1XQIFjnqGsNlskDs9od5UbgZzQbQbopaPDZi0k68Q9pW99foZhs3LOOuRDIPy548hKKdTScdKMbKdKvqIqo1AAPoABjVVK32pZes3DJvSA5XN5A9BQRN1RQvSVz1PSwrxXEl13vZ88XVcCzzpT8mx-U5yDHE1wGgOBECQa0ZDtBpggAJkdeV22cECWnjD1fE6H0kH9Rdgx6HskAYks5HYlNYg3AFLxrFZcwCIIQmEMJGKiVMyQKFU8VKfUt2zWsaCVRSoEGVSGSdKYOzophuw03t1k2bZdgOY4sOWf9J2nO5gPnJ5AyXOVlkVDCMR3Sc9wgIDOxFFEoI-NSiWvOCFIpdUwsg9C9IxX8HLoQDYUPYVjxRFCsQSiLPLXGLo0pXLwoZL9hKsD4KCOIA)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! Thanks to you I understood how what I was trying to do didn't make any sense. I ended up with simulating the lower bound with `P extends Partial<P> extends P ? object : never`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but depending on what exactly you want, you could choose either:

1. Only required fields.
2. Only optional fields.
3. Cast all fields to be optional.

where each of those options could be shallow (only top-level keys) or deep (every nested key of the previous level's keys).

I've done this before using these util types:

```js
/*************************************
 *** Sub-utils for ease of (re)use ***
 *** Optional, makes code more DRY ***
 *************************************/


/**
 * Same as Nullable except without `null`.
 */
export type Optional<T> = T | undefined;

/**
 * Opposite of built-in `NonNullable`.
 */
export type Nullable<T> = Optional<T> | null;

/**
 * Types that can be used to index native JavaScript types, (Object, Array, etc.).
 */
export type IndexSignature = string | number | symbol;

/**
 * An object of any index-able type to avoid conflicts between `{}`, `Record`, `object`, etc.
 */
export type Obj<O extends Record<IndexSignature, unknown> | object = Record<IndexSignature, unknown> | object> = {
    [K in keyof O as K extends never
        ? never
        : K
    ]: K extends never
        ? never
        : O[K] extends never
            ? never
            : O[K];
} & Omit<O, never>;

/**
 * Any type that is indexable using `string`, `number`, or `symbol`.
 *
 * Serves as a companion to {@link OwnKeys} while maintaining the generalizable usage of {@link Obj}.
 */
export type Indexable<ValueTypes = unknown> = (
    {
        [K: IndexSignature]: ValueTypes;
    }
    | Obj
);


/********************************************
 *** Actual typedefs to achieve your goal ***
 ********************************************/


/**
 * Picks only the optional properties from a type, removing the required ones.
 * Optionally, recurses through nested objects if `DEEP` is true.
 */
export type PickOptional<T, DEEP extends boolean = false> = { // `DEEP` must be false b/c `never` interferes with root level objects with both optional/required properties
    // If `undefined` extends the type of the value, it's optional (e.g. `undefined extends string | undefined`)
    [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K]
        ? K
        : never
    ]: DEEP extends false
        ? T[K]
        : T[K] extends Optional<Indexable> // Like above, we must include `undefined` so we can recurse through both nested keys in `{ myKey?: { optionalKey?: object, requiredKey: object }}`
            ? PickOptional<T[K], DEEP>
            : T[K];
};

/**
 * Picks only the required fields out of a type, removing the optional ones.
 * Optionally, recurses through nested objects if `DEEP` is true.
 */
export type PickRequired<T, DEEP extends boolean = false> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends keyof PickOptional<T, DEEP>
        ? never
        : K
    ]: T[K] extends Indexable
        ? PickRequired<T[K], DEEP>
        : T[K];
};

/**
 * Companion to built-in `Partial` except that it makes each nested property optional
 * as well.
 *
 * Each non-object key's value will be either:
 * - If `NT` (NewType) is left out, then the original type from `T` remains.
 * - The specified `NT` type.
 */
export type PartialDeep<T, NT = never> = T extends Indexable
    ? {
        // `?:` forces the key to be optional
        [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Indexable
            ? Nullable<PartialDeep<T[K], NT>>
            : NT extends never
                ? Nullable<T[K]>
                : Nullable<NT>
    }
    : NT extends never
        ? Nullable<T>
        : Nullable<NT>;
```

For your case, you could use them like:

```js
// Includes both `P extends undefined` and `P extends object`
export function someFunc<P extends Optional<Indexable>>(params: P): string;
// Only includes optional keys from `P extends object`
export function someFunc<P extends PickOptional<Indexable>>(params: P): string;
// What I think you're seeking which is that every key is optional
export function someFunc<P extends PartialDeep<Indexable>>(params: P): string;
// Actual implementation needs to allow for each of:
// - undefined
// - object
// - PickOptional<object>
// - PartialDeep<object>`
export function someFunc<P extends Optional<PartialDeep<Indexable>>>(params: P) {
    return params ? JSON.stringify(params) : 'No params';
}
```

While I added an incomplete implementation, it at least shows how you could use the overloads and type utils.